# Operator overloading of (*,+,-,/,=)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload (*,+,-,/,=) opertors in `FLOAT` class. I wrote this class:

```
class FLOAT{
private:
float x;
public:
FLOAT(){    x=0.0;  }
void setFloat(float f)      {   x=f;    }
void operator+(FLOAT obj)   {x=x+obj.x; };
void operator-(FLOAT obj)   {x=x-obj.x; };
void operator*(FLOAT obj)   {x=x*obj.x; };
void operator/(FLOAT obj)   {x=x/obj.x; };
FLOAT& operator=(const FLOAT& obj)  {this->x=obj.x; return *this;   };
};
```

and I use it such:

```
int main() {
FLOAT f,f2,f3;
f.setFloat(4);
f2.setFloat(5);

f3=f+f2;// here is the problem!
    system("pause");//to pause console screen
return 0;
}
```

`f3=f+f2` seems not right. What can I do?

Comment: I would highly recommend a copy constructor, and an implicit constructor from `float`.  Also passing objects by `const FLOAT&` where possible.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why?  What's wrong with the compiler generated copy ctor?  In fact, Adban, you can lose the assignment operator.  The compiler will provide that as well.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I keep forgetting the compiler sometimes provides those.  I prefer to see them explicitly, so I have a list of my options.  Same for assignment.  It's not needed, but neither is whitespace.

Comment: @MooingDuck: So, do you also write a move constructor and move assignment operator?  Even when the defaults will do?  Seems like a lot of noise to me, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I do if I have non-POD or pointer members.  I'd use `= default` instead, but MSVC doesn't support it.  It only adds one line per function in the header, which isn't too much noise for me.  Personal preference though, you're right.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I thought you are interested only in C :) (I've read your *C Craft*)

Comment: @RomanB.: My what? [This?](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/c/index.html)  That's not me.  I'm not the least bit interested in C, except where it overlaps with C++, and those are the parts I'm least interested in.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oops. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your implementations of the operators will not do what you want.  For example:

```
FLOAT f1; f1.setFloat(1.0);
FLOAT f2; f2.setFloat(2.0);
FLOAT f3;
f3 = f1 + f2;
```

Assuming that you change operator+(), for example, to return a FLOAT, you will still have the effect that after the addition, f1 and f3 will both equal 3.0;

A commonly used idiom is to implement the operators like += in the class, and the operators like + outside the class.  For example:

```
class FLOAT {...
    FLOAT& operator+=(const FLOAT& f)
    {
        x += f.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

...

```
FLOAT operator+(const FLOAT& f1, const FLOAT& f2)
{
    FLOAT result(f1);
    f1 += f2;
    return f1;
}
```

A side benefit of this is that you can also easily add other operators like

```
FLOAT operator+(int x, const FLOAT& f);
FLOAT operator+(double x, const FLOAT& f);
```

Doing a thorough job on a class like this is good practice for when you want to do this work with more interesting types like complex numbers or matrices.  Be sure you add the comparison operators, copy constructor, destructor and assignment operators for completeness.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Your operators are the equivalent of `+=`, `-=`, etc.
If you want to +, you also need to return a value!

```
FLOAT operator+(FLOAT obj)
{
    FLOAT tmp;
    tmp.x = x+obj.x;
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't assign the return value of a void function to anything, because it doesn't return anything. Declaring the operator overloads as friend functions is frequently much more flexible. Your class and functions should be more like this:

```
class FLOAT { 
    friend FLOAT operator+( const FLOAT & a, const FLOAT & b );

   /* ... rest of class ... */
};


FLOAT operator+( const FLOAT & a, const FLOAT & b ) 
{
    FLOAT temp( a );
    temp.x += b.x; 
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should return the result in each case. Also pass an argument by reference so it will not be copied and add some `const` qualifiers. For `+` it might look like:

```
FLOAT operator+(const FLOAT& obj) const
{
    FLOAT res;
    res.x = x + obj.x;
    return res;
}
```

*Note* you might not want to return `const`, as you would like go get modifiable object.

Comment: My C++ is pretty weak, but this looks more like `+=` than `+`.

Answer (score 3):

```
void operator+(FLOAT obj)   {x=x+obj.x; };
```

What is wrong in this code?

It returns void and you want to assign this somewhere. No go.

```
FLOAT & FLOAT::operator=(const FLOAT &rhs) {
    ...  // todo assignment here
    return *this;  // Return a reference to myself.
}

FLOAT & FLOAT::operator+=(const FLOAT &rhs) {
   ...  //todo implement compound + operator
   return *this;  // Return a reference to myself.
  }

const FLOAT FLOAT::operator+(const FLOAT &rhs) const {
    return FLOAT(*this) += other; //that's already done :)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator+` has return type `void`. It should probably return a `FLOAT`.

To clarify by example, `void operator+(FLOAT obj)   {x=x+obj.x; };` should in stead look like `FLOAT operator+(FLOAT obj) { return obj.x + x; }`. This is because, as others have pointed out, a function with return type of `void` cannot return any value. Since `operator+` is generally expected to return a value that represents the result of addition, you should return a `FLOAT` object that holds this result.

Comment: Though accurate, this is not a answer that provides understanding of the problem and how to address it.